# How can I toggle the visibility of a <aside> element onclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have an `<aside>` element that I want to be able to hide. The sidebar is placed as a flexbox row child as the following CodePen shows: https://codepen.io/pc-magas/pen/RexvXq

I want to be able to hide it and reveal it again with successive clicks of the button, but my code is not working correctly. It is only hiding the element and not showing it again on successive clicks.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hideAside").on("click",function(){
      $('aside').toggle("slide",function(){
        var visibilityStatus=$('aside').attr("data-visible");
        alert(visibilityStatus);
        $('aside').attr('data-visible',!visibilityStatus);
      });
  })
})
```

```css
.content{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

aside{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 1px;
}

aside[data-visible="false"]{
   display: none !important;
   flex-direction: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <header>
    My Page
  </header>
  <div class="content">
    <aside data-visible="true">
      Aside Content
    </aside>
    <main>
      <button id="hideAside"> Hide Aside </button>
    </main>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Is there another reason that attribute `data-visible` exists or is it only for this purpose?

Comment: Add a class aside[data-visible="true"] { display: flex; }

Comment: @Steve0 it exists for that purpoce only.

Comment: Also remove !important on your display: none; and you are set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not actually need;

1. The css `aside[data-visible="false"]`
2. Or the slide `function`, `$("aside").toggle("slide")` is enough to make this all work.

But the issue with your code is that `var visibilityStatus = $('aside').attr("data-visible")` is a string and not a boolean.  By explicitly converting it to a boolean, your code will work as expected.

```
var visibilityStatus = $('aside').attr("data-visible") == true
```

> The conversion in javascript of "false" to `true` is described as coercion, and can sometimes result in unexpected ["truthy"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) values.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#hideAside").on("click", function() {
    $('aside').toggle("slide", function() {
      var visibilityStatus = $('aside').attr("data-visible") == true;
      console.log(visibilityStatus);
      $('aside').attr('data-visible', !visibilityStatus);
    });
  })
})
```

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

aside {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 1px;
}

aside[data-visible="false"] {
  display: none !important;
  flex-direction: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body>
  <header>
    My Page
  </header>
  <div class="content">
    <aside data-visible="true">
      Aside Content
    </aside>
    <main>
      <button id="hideAside"> Hide Aside </button>
    </main>
  </div>
</body>
```

**EDIT** Below is the version that functions and I only stripped out unnecessary code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#hideAside").on("click", function() {
    $('aside').toggle("slide");
  })
})
```

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

aside {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body>
  <header>
    My Page
  </header>
  <div class="content">
    <aside>
      Aside Content
    </aside>
    <main>
      <button id="hideAside"> Hide Aside </button>
    </main>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

The code pen works as expected with the following change to your css, just having one `aside` with data-attribute defined and toggling the same from your code would and should as you are already doing.

```
aside[data-visible="true"] { 
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

https://codepen.io/jayas/pen/bmaZXg - edited version of yours which has only one aside defined inside of CSS

Comment: Is there alternative method available for this in angular?

Answer (score 1):

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#hideAside").on("click",function(){
          $('aside').toggle("slide",function(){
            var visibilityStatus=$('aside').attr("data-visible");
            $('aside').attr('data-visible',visibilityStatus);
          });
      })
    })
```

```css
    .content{
      display:flex;
      flex-direction: row;
    }
    
    aside{
      display:flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      margin-left: 1px;
    }
    
    aside[data-visible="false"]{
       display: none !important;
       flex-direction: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
      <header>
        My Page
      </header>
      <div class="content">
        <aside data-visible="true">
          Aside Content
        </aside>
        <main>
          <button id="hideAside"> Hide Aside </button>
        </main>
      </div>
    </body>
```

Maybe like this?